# Uniform continuity of the function $f(x)= \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x+\log x}$ in the set $E=[1,+ \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

I have the function $f(x)= \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x+\log x}$ in the set $E=[1,+ \infty)$and I have  to discuss the uniform continuity of f in E.

I've calculated the derivative $y'$ and it tends to $0$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$

Can this fact be used to prove that $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous in $E$?

Comment: What about $\lim_{x\to 1+} f'(x)$?

Comment: I'm afraid that this limit is$+ \infty$

Comment: @Math1000 but the function is bounded

Comment: Here is a hint.  Can you show that $0\leq f(y)-f(x) \leq f(y-x+1)$ whenever $y>x\geq 1$?

Answer (score 0):

For all $ \epsilon> 0 $ sufficiently close to zero  such that $\sqrt{x^2-1}-\epsilon>0$ we have
$$
\frac{1}{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}-\epsilon}+\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}-\epsilon}}= \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}-\epsilon}{x+\log x}\leq \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x+\log x} \leq \frac{x}{x+\log x}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{\log x}{x}}.
$$
Once $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\log x}{x}=0$, $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}-\epsilon}=1$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}-\epsilon}=0$ we have
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x+\log x} =1
$$
In each compact interval $ [1, c] $ the function $ f $ is uniformly continuous because all continuous functions in a compact interval are uniformly continuous. On the other hand, any function approaching a constant at infinity is uniformly continuous in a interval $ [c, \infty) $ to some convenient $ c $.

Answer (score 0):

For $x\in [1,2]$, use continuity on a compact set $\implies$ uniform continuity to find a $\delta_1$ which depends only on epsilon. On $[2,\infty)$, use the fact you mentioned to show that $f$ is in fact Lipschitz, so of course there is a $\delta_2$ which depends only on epsilon.

Take $\delta=\min\{ \delta_1,\delta_2\}$.